# ModelForm returning server error (500)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

See the code below. I'm trying to use ModelForms to add records to a database, but it keeps returning the server error - seemingly against the .save() action, but I'm not quite sure. Any help towards how I can fix this would be really appreciated.

```
#view.py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from forms import ContactForm, wallForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from home.models import wall
from django.forms import ModelForm
def wallpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_post = wallForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.cleaned_data['postContent']
            new_post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = wallForm()
    return render(request, 'home/wall_post.html', {'form': form,})

#model.py
from django.db import models

class wall(models.Model):
    clusterId = models.ForeignKey(cluster)
    userId = models.ForeignKey(user)
    postContent = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_timestamp = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    clusterId.blank = True
    userId.blank = True
    postContent.blank = True
    likes.blank = True
    post_timestamp.blank = True

#forms.py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from home.models import wall

class wallForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = wall

#template.py
<h1>Posting test</h1>

{% if form.errors %}
    <p style="color: red;">
        Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
    </p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_p }}
    </table>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<b><a href = "/home/">Go back...</a></b>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
def wallpost(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_post = wallForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.cleaned_data['postContent']
            new_post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = wallForm()
    return render(request, 'home/wall_post.html', {'form': form,})
```

In this line `if form.is_valid()`, `form` is not actually defined. You probably want `if new_post.is_valid()`, and similarly `form.cleaned_data` should be `new_post.cleaned_data`.

Also, its not clear what you are doing with this line `f = form.cleaned_data['postContent']`, because you don't use `f` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, the 'new_post' had just recently been introduced as part of some debugging I was trying. Ill try your code shortly and repost. Thanks so far!

Comment: If you set `DEBUG=True` in your `settings.py`, you'll should get a helpful stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. After setting debug = True, I realised that the error was coming from two different points.

1. Two of my foreign key fields in my model could not be empty (despite setting their model attribute blank = True). Once this was resolved, there was then an error in the database;
2. I'm not sure what caused the database error, but when I dropped the database, created a new one, and re-ran syncdb, everything seemed to work fine. Must have something to do with fields not lining up.

Thanks again for the help.